# Solutions to Dirichlet problem on manifolds with boundary

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, harmonic-functions

I am looking for a reference for the following assertion:

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with boundary, and $f:\partial M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth. Then there exists a unique smooth function $ w:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that $w|_{\partial M} = f$ and $ \Delta w = 0$ (where $ \Delta $ is the Laplacian on $M$).

In particular, does existence and uniqueness always hold?  (without any limitations on the curvature of $M$, I have seen sources which treat the special case of negative curvature like "Lectures on  Differential Geomery" by Schoen & Yau)

**The case which interests me most is the one when $M$ is a compact ball in $\mathbb{R^n}$ but the metric is arbitrary. (It might be different from the Euclidean)**

**Update:** As mentioned (in a comment by  Chris Gerig), uniqueness does not hold for noncompact manifolds. So lets narrow down the discussion to the compact case.

Comment: I think that this should be true if $M$ is compact, with exactly the same variational proof that you have on bounded domains in $\mathbb{R^n}$. (You can try looking in Gilbarg-Trudinger's book on elliptic PDEs).

Comment: And not true (for uniqueness) if $M$ is noncompact. You need a "bounded" assumption on the functions (which the Dirichlet problem typically assumes). Take $f=0$ and solutions $w_1=e^x\sin y$ and $w_2=0$ on the half-space $\lbrace(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;|\; y\ge0\rbrace$. The analytic function in the background is $e^z$.

Answer (score 2):

**For ball** in $\mathbb{R^n}$ it is easy. You can cover whole ball with one map(for example identity map :D) And write you equation $\Delta w =0$ in coordinates. This will only alter the Laplace operator a little bit and you end up solving equation in to form
$$
\nabla \cdot (A\,\nabla w) = 0
$$
Where
$$
A_{ij} = \sqrt{|g|} g^{ij}
$$
see wiki page on [Laplace-Beltrami operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator).

So you have standard Dirichlet problem problem in $\mathbb{R^n}$, therefore existence and uniqueness is guaranteed. If you want reference that for example consult Evans book on PDE.

---

On any compact manifold **with boundary**. I think that the result should be the same, in the proof existence on $\mathbb{R^n}$ you do not use any global  properties of $\mathbb{R^n}$. I think It should be reasonably easy to alter the existence proof from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to any compact manifold with boundary, but a little bit tedious because you have to develop theory of  Sobolev spaces on that manifold.

---

On compact manifold **without boundary**. Here I answer a question that has not been asked but seems to me interesting.

What about equation 
$$
\Delta w = g
$$

Here we have to be careful. Necessary condition on existence is $\int g = 0$. This can be seen from a little physical intuition. This equation can be considered as stationary solution of heat equation
$$ 
\partial_t w - \Delta w = g
$$
In stationary situation there has to be balance between energy inflow and outflow. Without boundary the cannot be any energy flow through it, thus the necessary condition $\int g = 0$. Although I do not know if it is sufficient condition for existence.

But it is probably very similar to the purely Neumann problem, where condition $\int g=0$ is sufficient.